# Where is my file saved locally?

Tags: ftp, curl

I've downloaded a file--I see the contents of my text file in the terminal window as it is downloaded in `curl`, but where is it saved on my local machine:

```
curl -v -O myFile.txt -u username:password  "ftp://myserver/myFilet.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

The file is will have downloaded to the directory you were in when you executed the curl command.

Comment: The directory from which I executed the command is empty.  And I can't search because of what appear to be permission restriction.  As I said I see the file and its contents in the cygwin terminal window but the file is nowhere to be found.  ?? Could it be because of a permissions error?? Thanks.

Comment: Got it--I was using an upper case 'O' in my command instead of a lowercase 'o'--I have no idea what 'O' was doing but 'o' downloads the file where I want it....Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download your files in predefined directory, for example, home. Use `curl -v -O ~/myFile.txt -u username:password "ftp://myserver/myFilet.txt";ls ~/` You'll see your file in your home folder

Another option is to `find` your file:

`find /* -name "myFile.txt"`

This will look for file on an entire root filesystem (`/*`) for exact match "myFile.txt".

Comment: I tried saving to home folder but I still can't find it nor does a search turn up anything bu a  lot of permissions denied to folders.  I'm using a cygwin terminal...

Comment: @PeterRobertson can you post screen listing, maybe omitting file contents and any hosts